# What is the color order for vte_terminal_set_colors palette?

Tags: gtk, color-scheme, vte

I want to implement Solarized color palette for a VTE Terminal. In the GTK+ documentation I can find the method how to set all colors. But there is no info about the color order in the palette:

http://developer.gnome.org/vte/unstable/VteTerminal.html#vte-terminal-set-colors

Where can I find it? I tried the order from the Solarized web page and it apparently does not match:

http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a serious omission from the docs. Try reporting it as a bug in VTE. For now, perhaps the order in the Preferences dialog of Gnome Terminal is the proper one?

Comment: So where is that solarized color palette for a VTE terminal? I need to know. It's a matter of life or death.

Comment: Find it in my codebase ;-) https://github.com/lzap/fourterm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the right order.

https://github.com/altercation/solarized/tree/master/xresources

See colorN entries and pair them with the termcolor column above the example. You get them in right order. Not ideal, but works ;-)

Comment: Hmm .. was looking for this info ... that link does not work any longer. It would be great if you still have this info

Comment: Fixed the link for ya, have fun!

Comment: thanks! also got a list i found here.. [xterm colors](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/)